# Labels y-axis change

Tags: r, ggplot2

I struggling a lot with a graph and I dont know what is going wrong. I got the following dataframe:

And then I use the following dataframe:

```
df <- read.table(text ="YEAR Eucaris Niet.Eucaris
1    8   81867    0.1527756
2    9   91507    0.1533734
3   10  102755    0.1733875
4   11  116491    0.1648633
5   12   55133    0.1771800
6   13   67115    0.1449571", header =TRUE)
```

This works but when I expand the dataframe

```
r <- c(14,56849)
df <- rbind(df, r)
```

The graph shows 8, 10, 12 in stead of 8,9,10 etc...

Why is this happening?

Comment: What code are you using to produce your plot? Also, are you aware that when you are `rbind`-ing, `r` has only 2 values but your `df` has **3** columns? So the `r` gets recycled out to length 3?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ggplot2`, by modifying `scale_x_continuous`:

```
library(ggplot2)
graph <- ggplot(df, aes(x = YEAR, y=Eucaris)) + 
  geom_line(linetype="dashed", size=1, colour="blue") + 
  geom_point(size=4, shape=22, colour="darkred", fill="pink")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:14)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Marc van der Peet if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.